# Bluetooth software suite

Tags: bluetooth, mobile-phone

I need something to backup my mobile phone contact book, send SMS etc. over bluetooth, I tried [Soleil](http://www.bluesoleil.com/) software but it does not work on my PC. Is there any other similar software?

I have Windows 7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, Blue Soleil is a Bluetooth stack and not actually a program for Mobile phones.

You still have a driver for the hardware - but A [Bluetooth Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_stack) is basically the layer after this that provides a nice interface and makes the hardware usable.

Whatever Bluetooth stack you use, you need to pair the phone with the machine - then after this, find a good piece of software that allows the features you want.

I cannot really recommend anything over anything else as I have not really studied all the options out there, but I know my dad does pretty much everything you want with [Mobile-Master](http://www.mobile-master.com/).